# How to select in select where the inner select is a substring of return result

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

This is beset illustrate by an example that I think should work but doesn't:

```
select * from TABLE_A where KEY in (
select substr(DYNAMIC_KEY,3) from TABLE_B where DYNAMIC_KEY like '$$%' and RECORD_ID='104251893783388824');
```

Basically, the inner select statement return a set of result which had  a '$$' prefix.  This is use as a lookup key in TABLE_A which does not contain the '$$' prefix in the key.

If I manually run the inner statement:

```
select substr(DYNAMIC_KEY,3) from TABLE_B where DYNAMIC_KEY like '$$%' and RECORD_ID='104251893783388824'
```

Copy the first result, let say '8462928318772288542' and run the outer select statement

```
select * from TABLE_A where KEY = '8462928318772288542'
```

This works.

However, if I ran is as a select in (select ...) statement, I get no result.

**Edit**:

The database used here is Oracle 10g.

The DYNAMIC_KEY column in TABLE_B is a VARCHAR2

The KEY column in TABLE_A is CHAR 32

Comment: The database used here is Oracle 10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem results from the comparison between datatypes "char(32)" in TABLE_A.KEY and "varchar2" in TABLE_B.DYNAMIC_KEY. The values in TABLE_A.KEY are blank padded by the dbms to the defined size of 32.

When you executed the subquery and copied the result into the outer query, you compared a column of type char(32) with a literal string, which the dbms treated like a char(32). Meaning, it was blank padded and thus the comparison worked.

In your original query you could change "`where KEY in (`" to "`where trim(KEY) in (`", then the query should work. The trim() function returns a varchar2 value.

Comment: Thanks.  The trim command on Key (the char 32 column) also worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TABLE_A.* 
FROM TABLE_A a
INNER JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.KEY = b.sbustr(DYNAMIC_KEY,3)
WHERE b.DYNAMIC_KEY like '$$%' AND b.RECORD_ID='104251893783388824'
```

Comment: I think if you alias TABLE_A as "a" you need to use the alias in the select list.  Not sure if this varies by database

Comment: Tried this out and fixed the syntax error above.  This also return empty results.

Comment: Actually this helped me resolve the issue.
The difference in column type is likely the cause of the problem (varchar2 vs char 32).

To resolve this, I used the statement suggested by Joel Coehoorn with a slight modification.

Replace 

a.KEY = substr(b.DYNAMIC_KEY,3) 

with

a.KEY like concat(substr(DYNAMIC_KEY,3), '%')

Answer (score 0):

substring requires 3 elements not two. Also I suspect there is a mismatch between the value of key and the value of the substring.

Comment: This is not the problem as running the inner select statements gives the correct result with the $$ prefixed removed.

Comment: Actually, the third parameter of substr() is optional

Answer (score 0):

Do you possibly have trailing blanks you need to trim out on either column?  Or possibly cast them both to the same data type?